# rails renaming associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models, TreeNode and User.  Each user `has_one` TreeNode, which is the root of the tree.

```
class TreeNode
  acts_as_tree
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_one :tree_node
end
```

I would like to have this setup so that rails will make the association so that I can do something like

```
User.first.tree
```

instead of

```
User.first.tree_node
```

How would one go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
has_one :tree, :class_name => "TreeNode"
```

Keep in mind, this assumes a foreign key called `user_id` in the `tree_nodes` table.

**Edit**: If that doesn't work, you *might* need to specify the foreign key (`:foreign_key => :user_id`), but I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently :class_name has been replaced with :source.

Comment: According to [the rails association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), both :class_name and :source still exist.  :source is for specifying the the source association of a `:has_one ... :through`