# User create a team or join a team after sign up / log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, associations

I'm currently working on a Ruby on Rails application where a devise user when successfully logged in / signed up can create a team or join a team. The user who creates the team will become the owner and can't belong to any other teams, a user that decides to join a team will see all teams that have been made and are able to join them. I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the relations I need to use for this

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable 
   validates_presence_of :phone, :city, :state, :street, :zip, presence: true, on: :create
      has_one :team     
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "team_name"
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "firstname"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User'  
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
   devise_for :users, path: 'users' , controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", confirmations: 'users/confirmations', registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

Am I using the right approach?

Comment: ive been stuck on this for several days please help

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Is this about the database normalization?

Comment: @mypetlion my question is how to create this association "the user who creates the team will become the owner and cant belong to any other teams, a user that decides to join a team will see all teams that have been made and are able to join them."

Comment: I guess there are different ways to do this. User has one team seems ok. For the team members you can use a 'has and belongs to many" relationship. Maybe by renaming the user class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169030/rails-renaming-associations so there is no collision between team Creator and team members. Regarding the fact that a user that has created a team cannot create another one, you can perform checks in the controller in order to block this ability. And disable in views as well with `unless current_user.team.present? `... (BTW habtm relationship means a joint table)

Comment: (actually I am not sure the renaming of the association can work with an habtm relationship... Maybe you can try and see. An habtm still looks like a good type of relationship for the team members in this setup)

Comment: Another solution would be to make the Teams the parent of the users: teams have many users. Users belong to many teams. And add a column "team Creator" as a Boolean to your User model. Though in order to find the team Creator you would have to make a `where` query to check that column value : `@team.users.where(team_creator: true)`. Or even better, create an instance method to the Team class. (And also you would have to check that a user joining a team is not flagged as a Creator)

Comment: @Maxence thanks for the insight im going to try this and will comment my updated code